# Alphabetizing in Java- error and warnings?

Tags: java, list, alphabet

I'm trying to create a program that alphabetizes a list, using the Collections.sort method and java.util.List, the Error is: 1 error and 15 warnings found:

```
Error: java.util.List is abstract; cannot be instantiated
--------------
** Warnings **
--------------
Warning: unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.List
Warning: unchecked method invocation: method sort in class java.util.Collections is applied to given types
  required: java.util.List<T>
  found: java.util.List
```

my code:

```
public static void preset(){
    List words= new List();
    words.add("apple");
    words.add("country");
    words.add("couch");
    words.add("shoe");
    words.add("school");
    words.add("computer");
    words.add("yesterday");
    words.add("wowza");
    words.add("happy");
    words.add("tomorrow");
    words.add("today");
    words.add("research");
    words.add("project");
    Collections.sort(words);




  } //end of method preset
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error said, `List` is abstract, you need some concrete implementation. In the case you posted, `ArrayList` will do.

Also note that you are using `List` as a raw type; don't do that (unless you are using a version before Java 5). Parameterize it with a type parameter (here, `String`).

Yet also: don't change the declaration of `words` to be `ArrayList`: `List` is good enough (normally), and by left it unchanged, you gain the ability to change the implementation later on.

In conclusion:

```
List<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();
```

or if using Java 7:

```
List<String> words= new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: THanks that works and also, how do i print this new sorted list? I was trying to print it by calling the method in the main, but that isn't working

Comment: Could you post how is it not working? System.out.println(words) should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can not instantiate `java.util.List`, but some of it's implementations. Like (for instance) `java.util.ArrayList`. Note that they are Generic.

Just fix the following:

```
 List words= new List();
```

to

```
 List<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();
```